# Tilde "~" in jquery selector obtains unexpected set

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a certain value the am checking if I can find radio buttons having Id attributes values starting with my value :

```
if($("input:radio[id^="+myValue+"]").length > 0)
{
   // some logic
}
```

For a certain convention I have, myValue shall evaluate to `~STR_2`, hence leading to the following selection evaluation `"input:radio[id^=~STR_2]"`.

There are no radio buttons in my page starting with such id `~STR_2`, but the obtained selection contains all the radio buttons on page and the length is > than zero.

I know that the tilde `~` operator is used for finding a string that contains a certain value but it is used as `~=` and not `=~`.

I hope anyone can explain the how this happened and what does it mean to have `^=~` altogether in a seletor.

**Note:** The issue was resolved when I used single quotes to wrap the value `$("input:radio[id^='"+myValue+"']")`

Comment: @Andreas how does that help? His question says he doesn't have any elements that are `~STR_2` yet jQuery is returning elements with that selector. And in HTML5, ~ is 100% acceptable in an id anyway.

Comment: Well I understand this convention, am just expecting the length to be zero in my case

Comment: @dman2306 I should read the question more carefully. Never mind... :|

Comment: This is a guess, but the jQuery docs say "Attribute values in selector expressions must follow the rules for W3C CSS selectors; in general, that means anything other than a valid identifier should be surrounded by quotation marks." In the rules for CSS selectors, a ~ would need to be quoted. So I wonder if perhaps it interprets the `id^=~STR_2` as "id starting with anything"? since it essentially ignores the parameter? Hence your expression basically evaluates to just `[id]`. Just an educated guess though.

Comment: @dman2306 This is good interpretation, I think it is most probably this way. I hope someone can verify what you said in an official way.

Comment: @KAD Agreed. The other possibility is it ignores the `[id^=]` entirely and is just returning all radios. You could test by creating a radio button without an `id` attribute and seeing if it's in a result set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't put my hands on the exact problem, but this seems to be a jQuery bug.

I was using jQuery library 1.6, and I have tried this example on multiple jQuery versions and started going up gradually in the version numbers. The selections gave the following error on jQuery version 1.8.

> Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression:
>   input:radio[id^=~]

Check the snippet which is running on a jQuery version less than 1.8, the selection gets all radios even the ones without an id attribute:

```js
var myValue = "~item34";
console.log($("input:radio[id^="+myValue+"]").length);
console.log($("input:radio[id^="+myValue+"]"));

if($("input:radio[id^="+myValue+"]").length > 0)
{
   $("#result").html("selection found " + $("input:radio[id^="+myValue+"]").length + " radio buttons");
}
else
{
  $("#result").html("no selection");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>


<input type="radio" name="test" id="item1"  value="1"/> A
<input type="radio" name="test" id="item2"  value="2"/> B
<input type="radio" name="test" id="item3"  value="3"/> C
<input type="radio" name="test" id="item4"  value="4"/> D
<input type="radio" name="test" value="5"/> E
<input type="radio" name="test" id="item6"  value="6"/> F
<input type="radio" name="test" id="item7"  value="7"/> G


<br />
<br />

<p id="result"></p>
```